# Disconnected from ETH websocket after timeout error [Python]

Tags: web3.py, events, python, logs, websocket

i'm trying to listen to eth websocket using python's web3 library, particularly listening to log events.

```
async def ws_v2_subscription_context_manager_example():
while True:
    try:
        async with AsyncWeb3.persistent_websocket(
            WebsocketProviderV2("wss://ethereum.publicnode.com")
        ) as w3:

            subscription_id = await w3.eth.subscribe("logs", subscription_params)
            while not unsubscribed:
                    async for response in w3.ws.listen_to_websocket():
                        print(response)
```

The code works great, im able to listen to logs in real time but thing is if i don't get events for 60 seconds conection will timeout, giving me this error:

> Caching response:
> response_id=-1,
> cache_key=6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88,
> response={'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': -1, 'error': {'code': -32000, 'message': 'Subscription timed out'}}

I know in node JS there's a feature of "ping" so the server knows the conection is still up, but couldn't find any parameter or config to do that in python, so it'd be great if i can send some kind of message to refresh timeout.

I tried sending a lastest block request to the server to try and refresh that but it keeps disconnecting me after 60 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the `WebsocketsProviderV2` and would love to help you troubleshoot this. I don't have enough "reputation" on here to post a comment but I will try to steer you in the right direction with my "answer" and if you're still having issues, please [create an issue in web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/new) so we can track it there.

**Clarification:**

It's difficult to tell what's causing that message. Based on the `-1` value for the `id` in that response, the client you're connecting to seems to not be following the conventional [JSON-RPC 2.0](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) spec already. My first inclination is to try a different client.

The response is definitely coming from your node so knowing more information about what you're connecting to will go a long way for debugging. There are a lot of documented issues in trying to use a third-party service with websockets. The best way to use websockets is to always run your own client(s) locally. If you are running your own node and still seeing this, it will be helpful to know what chain you are connecting to, what client(s) you are running, etc, so the debugging can be made easier.

**Ping / pong troubleshooting:**

As for the ping / pong question, the [WebsocketProviderV2](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#websocketproviderv2-beta) documentation explains the `websocket_kwargs` a bit. What this dictionary does is it passes the key / value arguments to the underlying websocket connection. Since the provider uses the python `websockets` library under the hood, this means you can pass in arguments to the connection that are defined in the `websockets` library.

That said, the websockets `ping_interval` argument is set to 30 seconds. This means every 30 seconds a ping is being sent via the connection. The `ping_timeout`, or how long we can wait for a pong, is also set to `300` seconds (5 minutes). You can try tweaking those but I don't imagine that will work in your case since the interval is already below the 60 seconds you mention.

If the underlying ping / pong is not keeping the subscription itself alive, it could very well be that the client you are running doesn't allow long-standing subscriptions that don't come in within a certain window. Either that or it doesn't allow this by default and you'd need to tweak the client configurations to extend the timeout to wait for responses for subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer felipe, you did my life easier with the library you wrote, it's been great help. Refering to the problem, i already tweeked those values you mentioned and it didn't change anything. I opened an issue here so we can track it better: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/3197

Comment: Thanks @germor197. I'm very happy to hear your life was made easier by the library and the provider! :)

I answered you there in that issue. It indeed doesn't seem to be an issue with the library then if other services work for you. This is a common issue with free tier third-party services. I directed you to a good resource in the issue, the Ethereum Python Discord server. 

Please, if you agree that this seems to indeed be an issue with the client / service you are using, I would appreciate you marking it as the answer. That can help me answer others here in the future. All the best.

Comment: I marked your answer :D, ty for the help although it wasn't a library problem, i'll definetly check that Discord. Best regards!